# Getting specific fields of nested elasticsearch document

Tags: json, database, elasticsearch

We have access to an api of all companies in denmark. There is a lot of data, necessary and unneccesary. We need to get a list business owners and directors.

The relevant list of Owners are nested four fields deep in the document. We loop over every 'organization', and loop over all the 'attributes' of the organization. If the attribute field 'type' is the string 'function' AND the field of a 'value' in 'attribute'(values is also a list, we however only want the first one) is on a whitelist(One of five strings) then we want the Value of the organizations 'name' field along with some other fields(the whole organization object would also be acceptable).

We currently take all these steps in a python loop, with 4 nested for loops for everything. This is a major PITA. I wan't to make this into an elasticsearch query(the api we query is alreasy es) but i have no major experience with DSL. Anyone know how this would be done?

Here is a gist of the 'path' we take to a given field: https://gist.github.com/mrcpj1998/e65c6988cf8aea9fcea4c4fb6c007c6f i also have a copy of the whole document [In JSON here](https://gist.github.com/mrcpj1998/866aee28a1425c0535066e55ccb1367e)

Comment: Do you mind pretty printing the JSON document?

Comment: The gist is now edited @Val

Comment: Geez, one hell of a piece of data...

Comment: And most of it irrelevant for our purposes. Therefore the need to use elasticsearch. The first gist listed is the json path to get to the field to check